# Android Cordova html5 jquery mobile video plays one time only

Tags: android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm new to Android. I have an iPhone cordova app that is currently published on the Apple Store. The app is written with Cordova, jQuery mobile, html5, css, js. I would like to add support for Android. I've compiled and run the app on the Android emulator and on a Kindle Fire device. The app runs fine --> except for the videos. Believe me when I say that I have searched before asking here. I rarely try posting on Stackoverflow. However, I am at my wit's end.

So the problem in steps:
From a dynamically generated jQuery mobile list view:

1. touch list item
2. goto page 2 that holds information and video
3. click video play button
4. Video plays
5. touch back button or navbar button go back to list items
6. select another list item
7. go to page 2 that displays video
8. click video play button and nothing happens.

I use a dynamic list that is filled using a json file of information (see below). User clicks on the list item (href) and user is taken to a new page that displays some information and the video player controls.

The first time the user clicks the list anchor selection,the page changes and the video player is generated. The user then selects the play button and the video starts playing. However, when the user navigates back to the list and selects another list item, the video player control is shown but the video does not play.

I use a standard HTML5 video tag (videoDemo is read from the json file as below):

```
<video src="videoDemo" controls height="auto" width="100%"> </video>
```

Here is a snip of one of object in the json file:

```
{
        "imageurl":"images/my.png",
        "levelLongDesc":"myLongDescription",
        "id":"2.",
        "name":"2. Name",
        "page":"gotoPage2",
        "description":"A description",
        "videoDemo":"images/videos/myVideo.mp4"
     },
```

I can post more code if needed. I just don't know what code snips to post. The app runs and is published on iPhone. I think this is something about android that I am missing. Your help, as always is appreciated. -Rachel

Comment: I have some questions. On what version of android you are trying? Are you storing videos in app or server or device? Does the video play for first time?

Comment: 1. Emulator: Android Version 6 (sdks for x86)

Comment: 1. Emulator: Android Version 6 (sdks for x86). Device: Kindle Fire DHX 2014(3rd gen) 4.4.3 (KitKat) 2.Videos stored in app--client side json. 3. Yes, video plays first time.

Comment: Also tried on Android 5.1.1. Kindle Fire. The video controls show up but video runs only one time when the control "play" is tapped.

Comment: Try reloading the video with `document.getElementsByTagName("Video")[0].load()`. This is what helped me out lately

Comment: Thanks njoye. I tried using your help, but couldn't see any difference. Maybe I wasn't using the statement properly. JQM behaves differently. I'm not a programming guru. I have to fight for every step. Appreciate your attempt at helping me solve this. I do think you may be on the right track. It is probably a refresh issue, but why it works perfectly on iOS and not on Android is a puzzle. Different browsers, maybe.